# Why does my special Codable protocol work differently than Swift's Codable with Array?

Tags: swift, protocols, codable, swift4.2

With `Codable`, I am able to create the following extension

```
extension Decodable {
    public static func decode(data: Data, decoder: JSONDecoder = .default) -> Self? {
        do {
            return try decoder.decode(self, from: data)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            CodableKit.log(message: "\(error.userInfo)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

and use it on both single objects and array types, for example

```
let person = Person.decode(data: personData)   // single
let people = [Person].decode(data: peopleData) // array
```

The 2 lines above compile without issues.

Now, I want to create a new protocol similar to `Codable`

```
public typealias JsonCodable = JsonDecodable & JsonEncodable

public protocol JsonDecodable: Decodable {
    static func decode(data: Data?, decoder: JSONDecoder) -> Self?
}

extension JsonDecodable {
    static func decode(data: Data?, decoder: JSONDecoder) -> Self? {
        ....
    }
}
```

When I use try to use `JsonDecodable` the same way I do with `Codable`, i get the following compiler error

> Type '[Person]' has no member 'decode';

```
let person = Person.decode(data: personData)   // this works
let people = [Person].decode(data: peopleData) // this does not
```

How can I get `JsonDecodable` to decode into an array of a model the same way I can when extending `Codable`?

Comment: Not related to your question but you should make your method throws, remove the do catch and return an non optional `public static func decode(data: Data, decoder: JSONDecoder = .default) throws -> Self {
        return try decoder.decode(self, from: data)
    }`

Comment: @LeoDabus noted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message might be more useful if it used the unsugared typename:

> Type 'Array<Person>' has no member 'decode';

`Person` may conform to your protocol, but `Array` does not. Swift explicitly declares that `Array`s are `Decodable` if their elements are. You just need to do the same:

```
extension Array : JsonDecodable where Element : JsonDecodable {
    static func decode(data: Data?, decoder: JSONDecoder) -> Self? {
        // Decode each element and return an array
    }
}
```

This uses a feature called ["Conditional Conformance"](https://swift.org/blog/conditional-conformance/), which allows containers generally to conform to a protocol if the type they hold also does.